# Error in Removing a file in python

Tags: python, database

I am trying to write a program for elementary database management.

The code is provided below:

```
class emp():
    def __init__(self,**kwds):
        self.__dict__.update(kwds)
e=emp()
try:
    fp=open('C:/EMP.txt','rb+')                             # open the file for reading
except:
    try:
        fp=open('C:/EMP.txt','wb+')                             # open the file for writing
    except:
        print 'cannot open file'
while 1:
    print "1.Add Records"
    print "2.List Records"
    print "3.Modify Records"
    print "4.Delete Records"
    print "0.Exit"
    print "Your choice"
    choice=eval(raw_input())
    def add():
        import os
        fp.seek(0,os.SEEK_END)
        another='Y'
        while another=='Y':
            print "\nEnter name,age and basic salary:"
            e.name=raw_input()
            e.age=eval(raw_input())
            e.bs=eval(raw_input())
            ch="%s %d %f" % (e.name,e.age,e.bs)
            fp.writelines("\n")
            fp.writelines(ch)
            print "Add another record(Y/N)"
            another=raw_input()
    def list():
        import os
        fp.seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)
        for line in fp:                                        # iterate over each line
            e.name, e.age, e.bs = line.split()                     # split it by whitespace
            e.age = int(e.age)                                     # convert age from string to int
            e.bs = float(e.bs)                                     # convert bs from string to float
            print "%s %d %f\n" %(e.name, e.age, e.bs)
    def modify():
        another='Y'
        while another=='Y':
            print "\nEnter name of employee to modify"
            empname=raw_input()
            import os
            fp.seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)
            for line in fp:
                e.name, e.age, e.bs=line.split()
                e.age = int(e.age)                                     # convert age from string to int
                e.bs = float(e.bs)
                if(cmp(e.name,empname)==0):
                    print "\nEnter new name,age & bs"
                    e.name=raw_input()
                    e.age=eval(raw_input())
                    e.bs=eval(raw_input())
                    fp.seek(-len(line),os.SEEK_CUR)
                    ch="%s %d %f" % (e.name,e.age,e.bs)
                    fp.writelines(ch)
                    break
            print "\nModify another Record(Y/N)"
            another=raw_input()
    def delete():
        another='Y'
        while another=='Y':
            print "\nEnter name of employee to delete"
            empname=raw_input()
            ft=open('C:/TEMP.txt','wb')
            fp=open('C:/EMP.txt','rb+')
            import os
            fp.seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)
            for line in fp:
                e.name, e.age, e.bs=line.split()
                e.age = int(e.age)                                     # convert age from string to int
                e.bs = float(e.bs)
                if(cmp(e.name,empname)!=0):
                    ch="%s %d %f" % (e.name,e.age,e.bs)
                    ft.writelines(ch)
                    ft.writelines("\n")
            fp.close()
            ft.close()
            import os
            os.remove("C:/EMP.txt")                           # Delete file EMP.txt
            os.rename( "C:/TEMP.txt", "C:/EMP.txt" )          # Rename a file from TEMP.txt to EMP.txt
            fp=open('C:/EMP.txt','rb+')
            print "Delete another record(Y/N)"
            another=raw_input()
    def exit():
        import sys
        fp.close()
        sys.exit(0)
    def switch(c):
        return {1: add,
                2: list,
                3: modify,
                4: delete,
                0: exit,
                }[c]()
    switch(choice)
```

The problem is coming in the segment of delete function when i am trying to remove the file "EMP.txt"...

It is giving an error:

```
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:/EMP.txt'
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: It doesn't appear you properly close your file handler before trying to reopen it, that might be the source of the issue.  Try using the ```with``` construct when working with files to avoid that

Comment: Since you're in a class, you should make ```fp``` an attribute of the class, so prepend ```self``` to it making ```self.fp```.  This will mean all of your functions will have access to the same object (which they currently don't)

Comment: @wnnmaw his code is not inside of his class, he just defined a class before writing module-level code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that you are opening the file EMP.txt twice.

I think there is no need to re-open the file in the delete function, or Try closing the file before reopening it.

Comment: When i am not reopening the file fp in delete(),then it's giving an error at line: "fp.seek(0,os.SEEK_SET)" 
error: local variable 'fp' referenced before assignment

Comment: Try adding `global fp` at the top of the delete function.

Comment: Now ,it is giving error at the os.rename statement:
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied

Comment: This seems to be a different issue now. Please check that you are able to rename the file in c: drive non-programatically. Might be related to permissions.

Comment: Is there any way to simply open a file without giving its full location?

Answer (score 0):

Sunny is correct, but there is a missing element to his solution.

You are continuing on to the `while` loop even if you cannot open the file. That is why you are getting the first error, the reference before assignment. You need to make the `while` loop only occur if you do not have an exception. There are many ways to do this, but I would take this approach:

```
try:
    fp=open('C:/EMP.txt','rb+')                             # open the file for reading
except Exception as e:
    try:
        fp=open('C:/EMP.txt','wb+')                             # open the file for writing
    except Exception as e:
        print 'cannot open file'
        raise    # or you could return here instead - depends on what you want
while:
    # ...
```

You could also set `fp = None` before you enter the try, and then before your `while` loop check for whether `fp == None`.

I would not use `global` in general, it has several implications in its effects. Also, I do not understand why you are redefining your functions every iteration of the loop, nor do I understand why you `import os` twice, but I would consider defining these functions outside of the loop, passing `fp` as an argument to them instead.